# Firebase Security issue in creating user accounts using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I've been using javascript to create users in firebase .this is the code given in the firebase guide

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
    ref.createUser({
      email    : "bobtony@firebase.com",
      password : "correcthorsebatterystaple"
}
```

this data is available for anyone from the browser console and can be a security threat (any one can create an account for themselves)
Is there any security measure i can take to prevent this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Absolutely,

The way firebase handles security is a bit different (by their own admission). Here are the basic concepts:

### Authentication

Firebase provides tools allowing for authentication, These include

- Integrations with Facebook, GitHub, Google, and Twitter authentication providers
- Email & password login, and account management
- Single-session anonymous login
- and custom login tokens

### Authorization

Firebase allows specify rules that live on the Firebase servers via an [Account Dashboard](https://www.firebase.com/account/#/)

### Data Validation

Firebase has a set of rules in the language that includes a .`validate` rule. Use it to specify declarative validation rules just like `.read` and `.write` rules

In your specific case, I would write declarative rules to limit the write access for your app. Something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "usersLocation": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false,          
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating an email+password account is not a write operations, But writing information about that account to your database is.